# Replace keyword in text by input with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input

i dev a angular app and i would like to replace some keyword like '[input-date]' by a input having 'date' type.

i try to use replace function with Regexp but doesn't work. it's shows me the code and not the input.

i was able to show the input with ng-bind-html but i can't use the value with ng-model.

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(output)"></div>
  <p>{{inputValue}}</p>
 </body>


var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.trustAsHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml;
  $scope.foo = 'some text {val}';
  var regexValue = new RegExp("{val}", "g");
  $scope.output = $scope.foo.replace(regexValue, '<input type="text" name="some_name" ng-model="inputValue" value="">');
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/nmML6X7y6poRvY6eY3K5

**EDIT**

i try something like that

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="plunker">
        <div  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <p ><date-input model="output" information="info"></date-input></p>
        </div>
      <script>
          var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
          app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
              $scope.output = 'Johan';
              $scope.info = [{
                "id": 0,
                "name": "i'm a name",
                "type": "text",
                "message": "Hello, i'm {{value}} and i love cacao"
              }];
          }]).directive('dateInput', function() {
              return {
                  restrict: 'E',
                  scope: {
                      model: '=model',
                      information: '=information'
                  },
                  template: function(){
                    var regexValue = new RegExp("{{value}}", "g");
                    return information.message.replace(regexValue, '<input type="date" ng-model="model">');
                  }
              };
          });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But

> Error: Can't find variable: information

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea to manipulate DOM in controller. AngularJS has directives for this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="plunker">
    <div  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <p><date-input name="info.name" message="info.message"></date-input></p>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
        app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.info = {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "Kostya",
                "type": "text",
                "message": "Hello, i'm {{name}} and i love cacao"
            };
        }]).directive('dateInput', ['$compile', function($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    name: '=name',
                    message: '=message'
                },
                template: '<span class="message">{{message}}</span><br>\n\
                            <input type="date" ng-model="name">',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.info = $compile(element.children('.message'))(scope);
                    scope.$watchCollection(['message', 'name'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
                        scope.info = $compile(element.children('.message'))(scope);
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, i should use directive but your example doesn't do what i want ... is it a directive example ?

Comment: My example replaces <date-input model="output"></date-input> with <input type="date" ng-model="model"> HTML. It has model attribute where you can pass variable to associate with input value. You can see "output" variable is changed when you type text in input.

Comment: I have suggested new answer. I used $compile instead of regexp to make it more flexible. If it deosn't work as expected please provide me with plain HTML example of what must be rendered at the end.

Comment: Thanx you to help me. it's not that but almost . i would this rendering : `<div>hello, i'am <input type="datetime" ng-model="value"> and i love cacao </div>`